# How to access only one object send by json not the whole array in ajax success function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to receive data from the controller to the view using json_encode and ajax functions. But I am sending to separate values through json, and I am tring to access it. So how can I separate those two objects, and get only a single value?

Let me show you my code:

```
 function check_relation_status()
    {
        var id=$('.id_data').attr('value');
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo base_url("user/check_relation_status"); ?>',
            data:{id:id},
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data)
            {   
                console.log(data);
                    var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
                var sender_Data = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                var senders_id=sender_Data.senders_id;
                
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'<?php  echo base_url("user/get_senders_data"); ?>',
                    data:{id:senders_id},
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                           console.log(data); 
                            var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
                             var sender_values = $.parseJSON(ParsedObject);
                        var senders_name=sender_values.sender_data;
                        // alert(senders_name);
                        $.each(sender_values, function(key,data) 
               {
                var uname = data.uname;
                // alert(uname);
               
                    $('#friendship_request').append('<div>'+uname +'has sent you a request</div>');
                     });
                    }
                });         

            }
        });
    }
```

now the controller code

```
public function get_senders_data()
{
$sender_id=$this->input->post('id');
$this->load->model('Pmodel');
$userdata=$this->Pmodel->getUserdata($sender_id);
$senders['senders_data']=$userdata;
$senders['senders_post'] = $this->Pmodel->get_all_count($sender_id);
// print_r($senders);
echo json_encode($senders);

}
```

the json value '$senders' holds both the values but when i try to access it usng 'each' function it shows the values two time when there is only a single column for uname . let me add some images to explain.

[image: json response]
[image: view]

Where I am wrong?

Comment: what is the output of `echo json_encode($senders);`?

Comment: are you running your 'each' call on the correct array element? or are you running it on a 'parent' array that has multiple children elements thinking is the array that should have only one 'uname'?

Comment: @JorgeObregon i am running the ajax on $senders that contain both the other values is there sometHing wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change like below:-

```
if(uname){
$('#friendship_request').html('<div>'+uname +'has sent you a request</div>');
}
```

Note:-

1.You are appending all usernames (which is not correct).

2.You are not checking that username is either undefined or null or empty etc

Comment: got it working @Anant but just for curiosity can you tell me why undefined was shown?

Comment: 1.you are appending all usernames.2.you are not checking names are undefined,null,empty etc